# How to use XmlObjectParser and XmlNamespaceDictionary? (google-http-client)

Tags: android, xml-parsing, google-api-java-client, google-http-client

Can anyone share helpful links or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample for accessing the calendar API, you can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/gdata/shared-sample-calendar/?repo=samples&r=fa8cee4b0d29abb1c7c595414f83fd7e6d9fd842).

It is a good starting point on how to roll you own XML mapping and use the google-api-java-client for accessing Google APIs that have not yet migrated to the new infrastructure. Based on this, I am using the google-api-java-client to talk to the Google Contact API.

UPDATE: there is a more recent example in the [samples repo](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout?repo=samples), look for the PicasaClient.java

Comment: The project has been moved off code.google.com to GitHub and your links are no longer active.